# Peripherals with Android (Rowboat) build on Beaglebone?

Tags: android, linux, beagleboard

If I use Texas Instrument's prebuilt Android image for Beaglebone (Rowboat), will I still be able to access the Sitara AM355x peripherals (PWM, I2C, GPIO, etc) via the Linux kernel? I have never used Android before, but I would eventually like to write my own UI to interact with some custom device drivers.

I know Android is built on top of Linux, but I'm asking if the kernel packaged with Android includes the AM355x peripherals (the Angstrom kernel does, for example).

Comment: Yes you can access the GPIO, I2C etc you need to use JNI interface

Answer (score 0):

`BeagleBone` Family comes with **`User Space Drivers`** for all Peripherals .

So developer can easily access the Peripherals using **`"Echo" & "Cat"`** operations.

If you are going with `Android platform` you have to use `JNI for read/write` options .

You will get [user guide for AM335x PSP from here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_PSP_User's_Guide) to access all the peripherals from user space .

Use `fcntl.h` to perform `open/close/read/write` operations.